# Variable as struct in global scope - how to define?

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct

First, i'm still learning C++ because I need to modify a programm to add some functions. In this program, I have a global state variable which is a struct. This is the idea/code:

```
struct {
   int counter;
   int x;
   int y;
} MyStruct;
```

This is defined in '.h' of main program and this 'variable' (MyStruct) are called in a lot of functions to get state and other informations.
The problem is that I need to send this information to a thread. I'm trying to create a thread (using pthread_create) and pass this 'variable' as a pointer to pthread_create function. This work fine. The problem is when I try to access any property of this struct in my thread function. I can't typecast my local variable to this struct, since this struct doesn't have a definition name! Is possible to access a property without struct name? I'm really trying to avoid changing this struct (even add a name for it).

My pthread create (works fine):

```
pthread_create(&proc_local_table_thread, NULL, procLocal, &MyStruct);
```

And my thread function (doesn't work):

```
void *procLocal(void *arg) {
    int *a = arg.x;
    // This doesn't work too
    //int *a = (struct Modes)arg.x;   
    // Code...
}
```

Comment: C or C++?  They are not the same, especially when dealing with `void` pointers.

Comment: [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not a good problem description.

Comment: `((struct Modes*)arg)->x` ;)

Comment: maybe try `((decltype(MyStruct)*) arg)->x;`. Either that or give your struct a name.

Comment: Since you tagged it with `C`, here is a `C` only solution: http://ideone.com/KovP7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`decltype`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) (c++11 and above)

```
void *procLocal(void *arg) {
    auto pMyStruct = static_cast<decltype(MyStruct)*>(arg);   

    int *a = &(pMyStruct->x);
}
```

Before c++11, I think you don't have any other choice to use what mch has said (ie http://ideone.com/KovP7x)